# Tiles don't render or it takes too long

Tags: leaflet, render, openstreetmap, tiles

The problem:
tiles are being rendered extremly long time (1 day or never)
The question:
What to do to make tiles loading and loading quickly? How to solve this problem?

The description:
While trying to increase tiles render speed I did reclustering described in this web site https://www.paulnorman.ca/blog/2016/06/improving-speed-with-reclustering/.
After doing this the tiles on my map started to generate even longer (tile rendering was slow even before).
Interesting that http://my_localhost/osm/0/0/0.png is loading quickly, and some tiles on 6-8 zoom are also loading. All the other tiles are not loading.

Renderd shows DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 34 closed, now 29 left.

I was looking for solution on the Internet, but I didn't find the solution.

renderd.conf:

```
[renderd]
stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
num_threads=10
tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile

[mapnik]
plugins_dir=/usr/lib/mapnik/2.0/input
font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
font_dir_recurse=false

[default]
URI=/osm/
TILEDIR=/var/lib/mod_tile
XML=/etc/mapnik-osm-data/osm.xml
DESCRIPTION=This is the standard osm mapnik style
```

Part of sites-available/tileserver.conf

```
    LoadTileConfigFile /etc/renderd.conf
    ModTileRequestTimeout 300
    ModTileMissingRequestTimeout 1800
    ModTileMaxLoadOld 2
    ModTileMaxLoadMissing 5
    ModTileRenderdSocketName /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
```

```
renderd[30436]: Rendering daemon started
renderd[30436]: Initiating request_queue
renderd[30436]: Parsing section renderd
renderd[30436]: Parsing render section 0
renderd[30436]: Parsing section mapnik
renderd[30436]: Parsing section default
renderd[30436]: config renderd: unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[30436]: config renderd: num_threads=10
renderd[30436]: config renderd: num_slaves=0
renderd[30436]: config renderd: tile_dir=/var/www/maps/tiles/cache
renderd[30436]: config renderd: stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[30436]: config mapnik:  plugins_dir=/usr/lib/mapnik/3.0/input
renderd[30436]: config mapnik:  font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu
renderd[30436]: config mapnik:  font_dir_recurse=0
renderd[30436]: config renderd(0): Active
renderd[30436]: config renderd(0): unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[30436]: config renderd(0): num_threads=10
renderd[30436]: config renderd(0): tile_dir=/var/www/maps/tiles/cache
renderd[30436]: config renderd(0): stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[30436]: config map 0:   name(default) file(/var/www/maps/tiles/styles/osm_bright/map_bright.xml) uri(/osm/) htcp() host()
renderd[30436]: Initialising unix server socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[30436]: Created server socket 3
renderd[30436]: Renderd is using mapnik version 3.0.22
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuMathTeXGyre.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
Running in foreground mode...
renderd[30436]: Starting stats thread
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/www/maps/tiles/cache
renderd[30436]: Loading parameterization function for 
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/www/maps/tiles/cache
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/www/maps/tiles/cache
renderd[30436]: Loading parameterization function for 
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/www/maps/tiles/cache
renderd[30436]: Loading parameterization function for 
renderd[30436]: Loading parameterization function for 
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/www/maps/tiles/cache
renderd[30436]: Loading parameterization function for 
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/www/maps/tiles/cache
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/www/maps/tiles/cache
renderd[30436]: Loading parameterization function for 
renderd[30436]: Loading parameterization function for 
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/www/maps/tiles/cache
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/www/maps/tiles/cache
renderd[30436]: Loading parameterization function for 
renderd[30436]: Loading parameterization function for 
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/www/maps/tiles/cache
renderd[30436]: Loading parameterization function for 
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-1'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-2'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-3'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-1'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-2'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-3'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-1'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-2'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-3'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-1'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-1'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-2'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-3'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-2'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-3'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-1'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-2'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-3'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-1'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-2'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-3'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-1'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-2'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-3'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-1'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-1'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-2'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-2'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-3'
Mapnik LOG> 2021-04-05 14:26:00: warning: unable to find face-name 'Unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-3'
renderd[30436]: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[30436]: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[30436]: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[30436]: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[30436]: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[30436]: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[30436]: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[30436]: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[30436]: Using web mercator projection settings
renderd[30436]: Using web mercator projection settings
...
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(621), y(352), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(621), y(353), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(620), y(352), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(625), y(352), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(625), y(353), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(621), y(354), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(626), y(353), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(620), y(352), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(626), y(352), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(625), y(354), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(620), y(353), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(626), y(354), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(623), y(354), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(620), y(354), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 61, number 49
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Got command Dirty fd(61) xml(default), z(10), x(624), y(353), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[30436]: DEBUG: Connection 48, fd 61 closed, now 48 left
```

Could you help me, please? Have a nice day.

Comment: Offtopic, since it is not a question about programming. Try asking at https://gis.stackexchange.com/ or https://help.openstreetmap.org/.

Comment: I suggest reading https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tirex and setting up some monitoring tools (munin/nagios) to locate your performance bottleneck.